# output a file based on condition - PHP

Tags: php, dreamhost

I want to make a PHP file, that get some information about user information (browser, platform, version ...) and if user comes from mobile, I'll output a mp3 file with average size: 20 MB.

I expect on average 30,000 users/day, I register with DreamHost Shared Hosting plan, do you think this plan can load such traffic, requests and processing?

what is the best way on PHP to fetch such information, insert into database and output a file based on condition?

Comment: Are those 30,000 users a day what you would *like* to have, or what a serious business plan predicts based on real data? :) If the former, you might be able to just start with shared hosting and move up when things work out.

Comment: Are the files you're outputting going to be personalized or are you simply giving the same file but distributing based on the user qualification?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Currently, I've ~ 30,000 users everyday, and I think it will count more after some updates. which plan do you suggest for dreamhost to fit my requirements?

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ I've about 100 files, user may choose which file to download

Comment: I call this post nonsense. You A. don't have 30000 users/day and B. Planning to download 20MB IF the user is on a cellphone doesn't sound smart to me.

Comment: @STTLCU currently, I've more than 4 million users for all my apps on Android, but daily, there are ~ 30,000 users.
I've media player app, so average size of a track is 20 MB. user may stream or download this track

Comment: You can't have such a large userbase and ask such basic questions.

Comment: actually, I was depending on free solutions, such as archive.org and other free hosting plans,distributing bandwidth among all available servers, but since I've more users daily, I moved to DreamHost paid plan, to make sure to serve user' request 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect if the user is on a mobile device you can use the [php-mobile-detect class](https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/). It's a lot easier than writing your own to accommodate all of the devices.

You'll need to watch the traffic patterns to determine whether you need a larger hosting plan or not. 30,000 visitors is a lot of visitors. 30,000 pageviews might be more likely to begin with (or even 30,000 visits). That being said the server load will all depend on when they come. 500 visitors connecting to your machine downloading the same file all at once can bring it down. On shared hosting as DS they'll likely try to have you upgrade to a VPS plan or a box where you're by yourself if you're receiving enough traffic to compromise the other people on the cluster. [They will also enable throttling if the site requires too much resources.](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Expecting_increased_web_traffic)

In terms of providing the link and limiting legitimate traffic, you can verify their IP address (`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`), their session id (`SESSION()`), a viewtime, and then pass that to a script for header redirection to prevent people accessing a shared link:

```
http://domain.com/download.php?f=04293D&ts=1367827755&t=25d55ad283aa400af464c76d713c07ad
```

On the page delivering the file you can verify that it's the same user, the same session (in case it's linking on a local network) and the timestamp.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!empty($_GET['f'])){
    $f = $_GET['f'];
    } else {
     exit();
    }

    if(!empty($_GET['ts'])&&preg_match('!^[0-9]+$!',$_GET['ts'])){
     $tsIn = $_GET['ts'];
    } else {
     exit();
    }

    $testHash = md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].session_id().$tsIn.'s@lt3d');

    if(!empty($_GET['t'])&&$testHash==$_GET['t']){

    // We'll be outputting an MP3
    header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');

    // It will be called audio.mp3
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="audio.mp3"');

    // To prevent mining the MP3 source is in the safe folder named '/._mp3s_safe/'
    readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/._mp3s_safe/original.mp3');

    } else {
      exit();
    }
?>
```

I've not included it in this code, but you can even check to see if the file was requested within a certain amount of time. You can also verify users by requiring them to provide their email address, then email them the link to download the file if traffic is an issue. Also you can use the timestamp hashing method to see if someone is using a program for downloads. If they've downloaded the file too quickly or have too many other downloads open then you can make them wait for the file or make the script stop with an error about too much traffic from their machine.

Answer (score 0):

To get user browser you can use: `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` you can refer `$_SERVER` for further information.